# Repurposing IIF statement for Redshift CASE

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm working with a query I was given from a client, but we have different SQL languages. We use Redshift, which doesn't include `iif` functions, and frankly, I've never used. I know it's basically a different way of a `CASE` statement, right? Here is the query

```
select
    *
    ,iif(datediff(day, 
        lag(event_date, 1, '1900-01-01') over (partition by client_id, error_id order by event_date), 
        event_date) <= 1 
    ,'yes',  'no') flag
from table.a
```

I thought this would work but it keeps firing back an error:

```
select
    *,
    CASE WHEN datediff(day, lag(event_date, 1, '1900-01-01')) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, errord_id ORDER BY event_date) <= 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END flag
from dsa.sas_days
```

Can someone help me in reconfiguring this?

Comment: extra `)` after `lag()`..which should be at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In redshift [Lag](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html), There are only two parameters in the function `value_expr` and `offset`.

> LAG (value_expr [, offset ])
>   [ IGNORE NULLS | RESPECT NULLS ]
>   OVER ( [ PARTITION BY window_partition ] ORDER BY window_ordering )

so You can try this.

```
select
    *,CASE WHEN 
         datediff(day, lag(event_date, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY client_id, errord_id ORDER BY event_date),event_date) <= 1 
        THEN 'YES' 
       ELSE 'NO' 
      END flag
from dsa.sas_days
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, I'm getting this error:

`Invalid operation: Default parameter not be supported for window function lag;
1 statement failed.`

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!